# Pass Data to Ionic from Native Activity

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I want to send strings from native activity to CordovaActivity(index.html). I don't have much experience in communication between Android activity and Ionic.

Can someone please help. May be share some documentation of the same. Thanks